# JSONSerializer EmberJS is not accepting expected format

Tags: ember.js

Based on the documentation here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_jsonserializer JSONSerializer is the right serializer for me to use for my API.

Despite that I receive the following error:

> ember.debug.js:28535 Error while processing route: core.admin.users
>   Cannot read property 'type' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'type' of undefined

The API response looks like this:

```
{
    "errors": [],
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "Foo",
            "last_name": "Bar"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "Moo",
            "last_name": "Boo"
        }
    ],
    "version": 1
}
```

My Model looks like so:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
    first_name: attr('string'),
    last_name: attr('string')

});
```

My Application Adapter:

```
import RESTAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/rest';

export default RESTAdapter.extend({
  headers:  {
      'Accepts': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

My User Adapter:

```
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
    buildURL: function(){
        return 'core/users/foobar';
    }
});
```

And finally my application Serializer:

```
import JSONSerializer from 'ember-data/serializers/json';

export default JSONSerializer.extend({
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because the `JSONSerializer` does not expect a root element in the response.

You would have to extend it yourself. Maybe like this:

```
normalizeResponse (store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload.data, id, requestType)
}
```

Comment: You are entirely right Lux. I was also missing the ID attribute from my objects. I will correct the question above